# c++ like languages

Tags: c++, compiled

I think C++ is one of the best known programming languages of all time, especially for low level programming stuff, but what other languages are a bit like C++ in means of capabilities?

edit: I want compiled, low level programming languages. Not languages like java.
edit: What I meant with c++ like language is this: A compiled, low level language, suitable for high performance applications, it doesn't have to be oop, but it should have similar capabilities as C++ (e.g. OS programming). I hope this makes my question more clear.

Comment: Really? I thought C was the best known programming languages of all time, especially for low level programming stuff. Have you heard of it? It's a little bit like C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_%28programming_language%29

Comment: D deserves more love. Definitely.